# How to update/edit core data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have seen other users ask this but I don't understand there code as I am a new user to iOS and xcode. I have implemented adding users as core data but I am not sure how I am able to update the records. I want to be able to either maybe select the user already in the system or type in their ID then update the rest of their record. Here is my data for the UIView Controller.

```
import UIKit

class AddScreen: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var studentID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var courseStudy: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var controller: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var gender: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.maximumValue = 99
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func stepperchanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let step = Int(stepper.value)
    age.text = String(step)
}

@IBAction func segController(_ sender: Any) {
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        gender.text = "Male"
    }
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        gender.text = "Female"
    }
}

@IBAction func addStudent(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.storeStudentInfo(studentID: Int(studentID.text!)!, firstName: firstName.text!, lastName: lastName.text!, gender: gender.text!, courseStudy: courseStudy.text!, age: Int(age.text!)!, address: address.text!)
    studentID.text = ""
    firstName.text = ""
    lastName.text = ""
    courseStudy.text = ""
    age.text = "0"
    address.text = ""
}

@IBAction func editStudent(_ sender: Any) {
    //Update student here?
}
```

And this is my AppDelegate.swift file code:

```
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
as! AppDelegate
    return
appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func storeStudentInfo (studentID: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, gender: String, courseStudy: String, age: Int, address: String) {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Student", in: context)
    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    transc.setValue(studentID, forKey: "studentID")
    transc.setValue(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    transc.setValue(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    transc.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
    transc.setValue(courseStudy, forKey: "courseStudy")
    transc.setValue(age, forKey: "age")
    transc.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch { }
}

func getStudentInfo () -> String {
    var info = ""
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Student> = Student.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            let studentID = String(trans.value(forKey: "studentID") as! Int)
            let firstName = trans.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String
            let lastName = trans.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String
            let gender = trans.value(forKey: "gender") as! String
            let courseStudy = trans.value(forKey: "courseStudy") as! String
            let age = String(trans.value(forKey: "age") as! Int)
            let address = trans.value(forKey: "address") as! String
            info = info + studentID + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + gender  + ", " + courseStudy + ", " + age + ", " + address + "\n" + "\n"
        }
        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
        return info;
    }

func removeRecords () {
    let context = getContext()
    let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Student")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)

    do {
        try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print ("There was an error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the `AppDelegate` for that. You want an `StudentManager` to manage your CRUD's of the Student.

So I would do something like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class StudentManager {

   func createStudent(_ name: String, address: String) {

       let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
       let entity_student =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Student", in:managedContext)

       let student = Student(entity: entity_student!, insertInto: managedContext)

       student.name = name
       student.address = address

       do {
           try managedContext.save()
       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }

   func removeAllStudents() {

       let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Student")
       fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

       do {
           let students = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Student]

           for student in students {
               managedContext.delete(student)
           }

           try managedContext.save()

       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not delete \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }

   func removeStudent(_ student: Student) {

       let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
       managedContext.delete(student)

       do {
           try managedContext.save()

       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not delete \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }

   func updateStudent(_ student: Student, name: String, address: String) {

       let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

       student.name = name
       student.address = address

       do {
           try managedContext.save()
       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
   }
}
```

You can use this in your `AddScreen` with

```
let studentManager = StudentManager()
studentManager.createStudent("aName", address: "anAddress")
```

So there is no need to write your code in AppDelegate

As you can see, you can edit an entity just by changing the values of its attributes and save it.

Normally you have a list of students in a table view provided from student objects like `[Student]`

You need to pass the selected student object to the EditScreen (or whatever).

If you have your student you can easily update it with:

```
var student: Student! // passed from table view

@IBAction func editStudent(_ sender: Any) {
    //Update student here?
    let studentManager = StudentManager()
    studentManager.updateStudent(student, name: "anotherName", address: "AnotherAddress")
}
```